# ImportError: Couldn't import Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm

клонировал django проект с гитхаба. На пк на котором изначально велась разработка все работало. Клонировал, создал виртуальное окружение в pycharm. Скачал django. Ввожу python manage.py migrate и получаю следующее:

> File "manage.py", line 16
>       ) from exc
>            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

тогда попробывал ввести python3 manage.py migrate и получил уже немного другую ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in
>   main
>       from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 21, in
>   
>       main()   File "manage.py", line 16, in main
>       ) from exc ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did
>   you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

по каким-то причинам мой проект не видел установленного django через file->settings->Project Interpreter-> + -> Django -> Install
Поэтому я установил так: pip install Django, теперь все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема.
Джанго был установлен при создании виртуальной среды.
Потом установил его через консоль виндоус pip install django и всё заработало.

Answer (score -2):

Нужно установить модуль отдельно в pycharm.
Пример установки - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJ9bTO5yYw0